# File transfer using the boost::asio libary

Tags: c++, tcp, boost-asio

Sadly when I try to transfer a file from my nfoserver to my PC is reads the filesize incorrectly and never ends the do while loop. Any help would be appriciated! It stops when the correct filesize has been sent, but doesnt reach eof, as it reads the wrong filesize from the server. I really don't know whats causing this, as I don't have much experience with the boost::asio libary or networking in general. That's why any help would be greatly appreciated, so I can understand the libary just a bit better :)

Client:

```
void receive_file_content_over_tcp(const std::string& filePath, boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket& socket) {
    std::ofstream file(filePath, std::ios::binary | std::ios::trunc);
    if (!file.is_open()) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to open file for receiving." << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    boost::asio::streambuf receive_buffer;
    boost::asio::streambuf fileSizeBuffer;
    boost::system::error_code error;

    std::size_t totalBytesReceived = 0;
    std::size_t fileSize = 0;

    // Receive file size
    boost::asio::read(socket, fileSizeBuffer, boost::asio::transfer_exactly(sizeof(std::size_t)), error);

    if (error) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to receive file size: " << error.message() << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    // Extract file size from the buffer
    std::istream fileSizeStream(&fileSizeBuffer);
    fileSizeStream.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&fileSize), sizeof(std::size_t));

    std::cout << "Receiving file. File size: " << fileSize << " bytes." << std::endl;

    // Receive file content
    while (totalBytesReceived < fileSize) {
        std::size_t bytesRead = boost::asio::read(socket, receive_buffer, boost::asio::transfer_at_least(1), error);

        if (error && error != boost::asio::error::eof) {
            std::cerr << "Error while receiving file content: " << error.message() << std::endl;
            return;
        }

        if (bytesRead > 0) {
            // Write the received data to the file
            totalBytesReceived += bytesRead;
            std::istream is(&receive_buffer);
            file << is.rdbuf();

            // Display progress
            std::cout << "Received: " << totalBytesReceived << " bytes out of " << fileSize << " bytes (" << (totalBytesReceived * 100 / fileSize) << "%)." << std::endl;
        }
    }

    std::cout << "File content received successfully. Total bytes received: " << totalBytesReceived << std::endl;
}
```

Server:

```
void send_file_content_over_tcp(const std::string& filePath, boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket& socket) {
    std::ifstream file(filePath, std::ios::binary | std::ios::ate);
    if (!file.is_open()) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to open file for sending." << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    // Get the file size
    std::size_t fileSize = file.tellg();
    file.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);

    // Create a buffer to hold the file content
    std::vector<char> buffer(fileSize);
    if (!file.read(buffer.data(), fileSize)) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to read file for sending." << std::endl;
        return;
    }
    std::cout << "File read successfully. File size: " << fileSize << " bytes." << std::endl;

    // Send the file content
    boost::system::error_code error;
    std::size_t bytesSent = boost::asio::write(socket, boost::asio::buffer(buffer), error);

    if (error) {
        std::cerr << "Error while sending file content: " << error.message() << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "File content sent successfully. Bytes sent: " << bytesSent << std::endl;
    }
}
```

I expect it to read the correct file size and transfer it, but the output is as follows:

Receiving file. File size: 12894362189 bytes.

Received: 512 bytes out of 12894362189 bytes (0%).

Server output:

File read successfully. File size: 2975744 bytes.

File content sent successfully. Bytes sent: 2975744
The file is ~2.9mb big.

I tried many things over the past few days, but it never broke the loop with the eof flag. So if you could help me that would make my day very much! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You never send the size in `send_file_contents`. Why would you expect to read it?

Even when you do, you need to make sure you send it portably (taking into account endianness, e.g.), e.g. using

```
 using NetworkSize = boost::endian::big_uint64_t;
```

I'd simplify the sending, and include the size:

```
static std::vector<char> read_file(path const& fspec) {
    std::ifstream file(fspec, std::ios::binary);
    return std::vector<char>(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(file), {});
}

void send_file_content_over_tcp(path const& fspec, tcp::socket& socket) {
    auto const contents = read_file(fspec);
    std::cout << "File read successfully. File size: " << contents.size() << " bytes." << std::endl;

    // Send the file content
    NetworkSize fileSize = contents.size();

    std::vector<asio::const_buffer> payload{
        asio::buffer(&fileSize, sizeof(fileSize)),
        asio::buffer(contents),
    };
    error_code ec;
    auto       n = write(socket, payload, ec);

    std::cout << "Content bytes sent: " << n << " (" << ec.message() << ")\n";
}
```

Now you can receive it completely symmetrically:

```
void receive_file_content_over_tcp(path fspec, tcp::socket& socket) {
    error_code  ec;
    NetworkSize expected = 0;
    read(socket, asio::buffer(&expected, sizeof(expected)), ec);
    std::cout << "Expected file size: " << expected << " bytes (" << ec.message() << ")" << std::endl;

    if (!ec.failed()) {
        std::vector<char> data(expected);
        size_t actual = read(socket, asio::buffer(data), ec);

        std::cout << "Received " << actual << "/" << expected << ": " << ec.message();

        if (!ec || (actual == expected && ec == asio::error::eof)) {
            std::cout << "File content received successfully." << std::endl;
            std::ofstream(fspec, std::ios::binary | std::ios::trunc) //
                .write(data.data(), data.size());
        }
    }
}
```

This can be tested to work: **[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/028f8e98eaaec833)**

```cpp
int main() {
    asio::io_context ioc;

    std::thread server([ex = ioc.get_executor()] {
        auto s = tcp::acceptor(ex, {{}, 7878}).accept();
        send_file_content_over_tcp("main.cpp", s);
    });

    ::sleep(1); // make sure server is accepting
    {
        tcp::socket client(ioc);
        client.connect({{}, 7878});
        receive_file_content_over_tcp("main-clone.cpp", client);
    }

    server.join();
}
```

Printing:

```
g++ -std=c++20 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp && ./a.out
md5sum *.cpp
File read successfully. File size: 2265 bytes.
Content bytes sent: 2273 (Success)
Expected file size: 2265 bytes (Success)
Received 2265/2265: SuccessFile content received successfully.
d47f7c90dfe3ca271f81ca203d53798e  main-clone.cpp
d47f7c90dfe3ca271f81ca203d53798e  main.cpp
```

### Streaming

Your send isn't streaming, so I assumed it wasn't important. If it **is**, just read blockwise: **[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/97b8d7d4d68da2ea)**

```
std::ofstream ofs(fspec, std::ios::trunc);
// ofs.exceptions(std::ios::badbit | std::ios::failbit);

for (std::array<char, 1024> buf; expected && !ec;) {
    size_t actual = read(socket, asio::buffer(buf), ec);
    assert(actual <= expected);

    std::cout << "Received " << actual << "/" << expected << ": " << ec.message() << "\n";
    ofs.write(buf.data(), actual);

    expected -= actual;
}
if (ofs.good() && expected == 0 && (!ec || ec == asio::error::eof))
    std::cout << "File content received successfully." << std::endl;
```

Printing

```
g++ -std=c++20 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp && ./a.out
md5sum *.cpp
File read successfully. File size: 2342 bytes.
Content bytes sent: 2350 (Success)
Expected file size: 2342 bytes (Success)
Received 1024/2342: Success
Received 1024/1318: Success
Received 294/294: End of file
File content received successfully.
fc9f108bcee2fd7f711ab7a63d81baae  main-clone.cpp
fc9f108bcee2fd7f711ab7a63d81baae  main.cpp
```

### What about `streambuf`?

It's not the right tool for the job. And you certainly should have used the a single buffer for all the reads. If you must, I think the following [would be decent](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b9ed4c4ccbc0d42c):

```
void receive_file_content_over_tcp(path fspec, tcp::socket& socket) {
    asio::streambuf buf;
    NetworkSize     expected = 0;

    error_code ec;
    auto       n = read(socket, buf, asio::transfer_exactly(sizeof(expected)), ec);
    std::memcpy(&expected, buf.data().data(), n);
    buf.consume(n);

    std::cout << "Expected file size: " << expected << " bytes (" << ec.message() << "), REMAINING "
              << buf.size() << std::endl;

    std::ofstream ofs(fspec, std::ios::trunc);
    // ofs.exceptions(std::ios::badbit | std::ios::failbit);

    while (expected && !ec) {
        size_t actual = read(socket, buf, asio::transfer_at_least(1024), ec);
        assert(actual <= expected);
        assert(buf.size() == actual);

        std::cout << "Received " << actual << "/" << expected << ": " << ec.message() << "\n";
        ofs << &buf;

        expected -= actual;
    }
    if (ofs.good() && expected == 0 && (!ec || ec == asio::error::eof))
        std::cout << "File content received successfully." << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Output with your exact code: Expected file size: 8872762386475541857 bytes (The operation completed successfully)
Press any key to continue . . . Sadly that doesn't work, too.

Comment: I can tell that's not my exact code because you can see it working live in the online demos. Can you edit the live demo to reproduce the problem? If you need a bigger file consider removing optimization and use a.out to test

Comment: E.g. in-memory https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/12d941046e17da5a or block-wise streaming https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0fbe39205ab5baec

Comment: Did you get anywhere since last time?

Comment: Sadly not, I use a different method now, streaming from an https server.